# text align right/ float right in embedded ruby not working without wrapping <p> tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to align "delete schedule" text to the right without aligning "stuff on the left" to the right.  Also don't want "delete schedule" on the next line, the result of wrapping a paragraph tag on that specific line and adding text-align: right.  Also tried styling with embedded ruby, didn't work either

```
      <div class= 'panel callout radius'>
       <li style="list-style-type: none">
       <%= 'stuff on the left' %>     
       <%= link_to 'Delete Schedule', session_schedule_path(session_schedule, to: request.fullpath), method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete your schedule?'}, style: 'text-align: right' %>
       </li>
     </div>
```

Comment: Do you see `style='text-align: right'` attribute in the HTML which is being generated?

Comment: @User089247 It's not generated in the HTML, I also tried wrapping a  span around that specific line of ruby and making sure the text-align: right was marked !important but it still didn't align it

Comment: Try :  `style: 'float: right'`